# Error insertando registros en una tabla de SQL Server Express copiando y pegando de Excel

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-express

Estoy intentando añadir estos 2 registros de la misma manera que he hecho con los otros 200, simplemente copiándolos de un Excel y pegándolos en la tabla y me dice en este caso concreto, que voy a tener clave primaria duplicada cuando los valores son distintos en el caso del campo SKU

[image: duplicado]

No entiendo la razón la verdad, pero de aquí no paso.

Un saludo

Comment: Refresca el cliente. Posiblemente lo hizo en tu primer intento pero puedes tener abierto `edit 200 rows`. Revisa en `select 1000 rows`...

Comment: Es difícil ayudarte, pero también es difícil, que el motor se confunda, porque es claro y explicito. ¿Será posible, que haya algún intro, o que alguna columna de más o menos, en la fila anterior o siguiente, que haga que el copy paste sea incorrecto. Pega la fila en un bloc de notas y pega una que sea correcta y compáralas. Y de otro modo, porque no copias primero una sola fila, y luego la otra.